# How to Adjust screen brightness on Dell Inspiron Mini 1010?

Tags: dell-mini-10

I just bought a used Dell Inspiron Mini 1010...and when I hit the brightness buttons (F4 and F5) it does nothing.  Is there a different way to adjust brightness, or how do I get these buttons to work!  I have tried hitting it while holding down the FN key as well, and it does nothing, please help!

Answer (score 2):

As you boot, at the grub menu, type <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the boot options.

On the linux (kernel) line, near `quiet splash` add `nolapic`

```
quiet splash nolapic
```

If that works, we can add it to the default boot options. Edit `/etc/default/grub`

```
# command line
sudo -e /etc/default/grub

#graphical
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to read

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nolapic"
```

Save your edit, then update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

If `nolapic` does not work, try `acpi_backlight=vendor`

Comment: "nolapic" did not work. "acpi_backlight=vendor" works! Thx!